# How to work with Jquery Popup window in Spring Application?

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, popup, highslide

In my Spring Application Display some models(jsp) like Popup window.

In that i'm using `[Apprise][1]Apprise[1]` Concept.

sample code ...

```
function edit_onClick() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "classes/editCreateEvent",
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            apprise(data);
        }
    });
}
```

It is show Spring return Model, like popup window.

But Problem is it is not take css and other scripting files.

So i'm thinking to Change `[Highslide Js][2]`iFrame .

But hear only handling Html pages not jsp pages.

```
<a  href="view_messages.html" class="copyright-text read_link" title="FAQ's" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', width:800} )"> )"Nurukurthiwebsoft</a>
```

So please help me how to diplay Jsp pages in iframe concept?

Comment: sorry above i'm adding two links about reference but it not displaying but ie. Apprise http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-The-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery and HighSlide http://highslide.com/

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly is the problem. JSP generates HTML page, so for example your link "view_messages.html" should be HTML page so you can display it in an iframe. Could you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the file extension of your page is .jsp you can still open it in a Highslide popup using the Highslide iframe method. 
See this barebones sample and replace the `href` with your .jsp page: http://highslide.com/examples/iframe.html

```
<a href="your-page.jsp" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe' } )">
    Content in iframe
</a>
```